# Some keys not being deleted in Redis

Tags: c#, azure, redis, stackexchange.redis

We use the StackExchange.Redis library to connect to the Redis cache in Azure in our C# application and noticed that some keys that we defined the expiration time are not being deleted, and this situation occurs randomly and we still cannot identify the source of the problem, basically we define the key and the expiration time as follows:

```
await redis.StringSetAsync(index, listJson);
await redis.KeyExpireAsync(index, DateTime.UtcNow.AddMinutes(5));
```

We are at a loss as to what to do to identify/fix the problem. Does anyone have any ideas what it could be and what we can do?

Comment: Can't tell you why. Can just ask why you do a second explicit call to KeyExpireAsync? StringSetAsync has an overload that takes the expiry TimeSpan already.

Comment: What does KeyExpireAsync return here?  From docs "For Redis versions <2.1.3, existing timeouts cannot be overwritten."

Comment: At the time I followed a tutorial to implement the use of the library to connect to Redis, it suggested the use of the KeyExpireAsync() function, do you believe it could be related to my problem? Because if that's the case, I withdraw the use of this function and pass the expiration time in the StringSetAsync function.

Comment: use try catch to trace what going on

Comment: Other method is using ```redisManager.DeleteKey(keyToDelete)```

Answer (score 0):

- Use Try and Catch to Trace to check where the code fails. For this, [SO](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/76202260/unable-to-save-data-to-azure-cache-for-redis/76205797#76205797) and thank you for the comments @**Ralf**.

[image]

- **Using Try and catch :**

With `redisManager.DeleteKey`

```cs
try
        {
            bool keyDeleted = redisDatabase.KeyDelete(key);

            if (keyDeleted)
            {
                Console.WriteLine("Key deleted successfully.");
            }
            else
            {
                Console.WriteLine("Key does not exist or failed to delete.");
            }
        }
        catch (RedisConnectionException ex)
        {
            Console.WriteLine("Redis connection error: " + ex.Message);
        }
        catch (RedisException ex)
        {
            Console.WriteLine("Redis error: " + ex.Message);
        }
        catch (Exception ex)
        {
            Console.WriteLine("An error occurred: " + ex.Message);
        }
    }
}

public class Program
{
    public static void Main(string[] args)
    {
     
        string redisConnectionString = "your-redis-connection-string";

        RedisManager redisManager = new RedisManager(redisConnectionString);

        // Replace "your-key-name" with the actual key you want to delete
        string keyToDelete = "your-key-name";

        redisManager.DeleteKey(keyToDelete);
    }
}
```

**Output:**

[image]